# Why must I need a controller for & expressing in directive?

Tags: angularjs

This works:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<div phone dial="callHome()"></div>
</div>

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.callHome = function(){
    alert('called.')
  }
})
.directive('phone',function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      dial: '&'
    },
    template: '<input type="button" ng-click="dial()" />'
  }
})
```

But this won't work:

```
<div phone dial="callHome()"></div>



angular.module('myApp')
.directive('phone',function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      dial: '&'
    },
    template: '<input type="button" ng-click="dial()" />',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.callHome = function(){
        alert('called.')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Why?

I want to use method in the directive without having the parent controller so it would be in its own isolated scope.

Answer (score 0):

It is searching for a expression in the parent scope. But you do not have parent scope instead you have the same scope.

```
    angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('phone',function(){
      return {
        scope: {
        },
        template: '<input type="button" ng-click="ctrl.callHome ()" />',
        controller: function(){
          this.callHome = function(){
            alert('called.')
          }
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
      }
    })
```

this should work.

Comment: sorry, didn't work for me. Causes an error. "asking for new/isolated scope on"

Comment: look at the the is an empty object that way you have an isolated scope. So you can have multiple directives on your page each one with it's scope and the controller method will be something like an static method of a class in java.

Answer (score 0):

`&` expression is set up with parent scope so there's no way to work with the methods by creating a new scope or isolated scope to work with that.

You must use parent scope to work with `&` expression.